# has_one polymorphic association select_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, has-one, has-one-through

Hi I have problem with make working select_box with has_one association.
I have model image_element which is polymorphic:

```
class ImageElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :image
end
```

model image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :application_id
  belongs_to :application
  has_many :image_elements, as: :imageable

  mount_uploader :image, ImagesUploader
end
```

and model level which has got following association:

```
has_one :image_element, as: :imageable 
  has_one :image, through: :image_element
accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_element
```

In the level form I'm trying to create the select_box to select an image_element for level.

```
= f.select(:image_element, ImageElement.all.collect{|i| i.image.image.thumb})
```

Select box is viewing properly but when i submit the form i have the following output from the server:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: image_element
```

Thank's in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `image_element_attributes` to `attr_accessible`

```
attr_accessible :image, :application_id, :image_element_attributes
```

Comment: I tried to build it with fields_for: = f.fields_for :image_element do |p| = p.select(:image, ImageElement.all.collect{|i| i.image.image.thumb}) And add to level attr_accessible :image_element_attributes but now i have the following error: Image(#80747460) expected, got String(#3361840)